# How to get order details on Order success page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, frontend, parent-child-theme

I need order details on file

```
app\design\frontend\Yard\yardfreak\Magento_Checkout\templates\success.phtml
```

In older versions , it works fine with these lines of code

```
$orderId = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getLastRealOrderId();
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
```

Please suggest me the alternative of the above give two lines in Magento 2.0.

Answer (score 4):

It already exists in the success block afaik but if not you have to get an instance of this class:

```
\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session
```

You need to inject it into your block class if you wanna use it in the template, assuming you have done this and can now reach it at the `protected $_checkoutSession` field you can run:

```
$this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder()->getIncrementId();
```

For the order you need:

```
\Magento\Sales\Model\OrderFactory
```

Assuming this is at `$_orderFactory` field you can use(This would however be redundant as the `getLastRealOrder()` above would give you the order):

```
$this->_orderFactory->create()->load($incrementId);
```

More on dependency injection and instantiating objects in Magento can be found at:

http://alanstorm.com/magento2_dependency_injection_2015

If you wanna skip the details above the final solution to get the order would simply be this:

```
$this->_checkoutSession->getLastRealOrder();
```

Happy coding!